# New to python. Need help to understand code

Tags: python

Hello I am new to python just started . Would be glad if someone can help me to understand this piece of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
   inputfile = ''
   outputfile = ''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
      sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
         inputfile = arg
      elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
         outputfile = arg
   print 'Input file is "', inputfile
   print 'Output file is "', outputfile

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Do you want a Flowchart // Flow Diagram for the explanation?

Comment: Please (re-)read "[ask]", then [edit] your question so that it contains an actual _question_ --- a specific question.  We have no idea what you want.  Also, show us what you've tried so far.  It looks like you've put no effort into this... so why should we?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my ability, please find my comments (`# comments`) below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# importing libraries    
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
   # defining empty string variables
   inputfile = ''
   outputfile = ''

   # try/except block. Try this code, if it fails, handle it
   try:
      # looks like you are parsing command line arguments
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
      sys.exit(2)
   #iterate through the cmd line arguments
   for opt, arg in opts:
      # of option is -h, do this (same with the following)
      if opt == '-h':
         print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
         inputfile = arg
      elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
         outputfile = arg
   print 'Input file is "', inputfile
   print 'Output file is "', outputfile

# python main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
   # call method main and pass the cmd line arguments
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```